# ReactJS - Calling a components method from another component?

Tags: reactjs

Is it possible to call a method on another component?

I have created that needs to be toggled either on click, or when a certain event happens.

For example I've created a React component that functions as a play button on a media player. I use LottieJS and bodymovin to animate the SVG button. If the song is playing the button shows a pause symbol. If the song is stopped it shows a play symbol.

Here's my `PlayButton` component ...

```
import React from 'react';
import Lottie from 'react-lottie';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import * as animationData from './button.json';

const Button = styled.button`
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    background: none;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 10%;
    margin-top: 27px;
`;

export default class PlayButton extends React.Component {
    static propTypes = {
        onClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    }

    static defaultProps = {
        onClick: () => {}
    }

    state = {
        isStopped: true,
        direction: 1,
        speed: 3,
    }

    toggle = () => {
        const {isStopped, direction} = this.state;
        if (!isStopped) {
          this.setState({direction: direction * -1})
        }
        this.setState({isStopped: false});
        this.props.onclick();
    }

    render() {
        const defaultOptions = {
            loop: false,
            autoplay: false, 
            animationData: animationData,
            rendererSettings: {
                preserveAspectRatio: 'xMidYMid slice',
            },
        };

        return (
            <Button onClick={this.toggle}>
                <Lottie 
                    options={defaultOptions}
                    isStopped={this.state.isStopped}
                    speed={this.state.speed}
                    direction={this.state.direction}
                />
            </Button>
        )
    }
}
```

I render like so:

```
<PlayButton onclick={this.playButtonClicked} />
```

When the button is clicked it will toggle the SVG animation using LottieJS.

I need to call `toggle` so that when the track has reached the end the play button will toggle from playing, to stopped. Is this possible at all?

Normally I wouldn't have this problem if I was using non animated SVG's. I would just display a CSS `background-image` depending on the state. But because this is a toggle animation I'm not sure how to go about this.

Comment: You should not have one component call a method from another component. Instead you should implement this with Redux and have the `PlayButton` subscribe to the MediaPlayer

Comment: I know you shouldn't, but I am not aware of the pattern used for this sort of problem which is why I posted the question in a such a way. My problem with Redux is it feels OTT for such a small task. Surely this is a common enough problem to solve with React alone?

Comment: How about passing the function in props?

Comment: @Hoyen From a very technical point, yes that's the case but its usage is quite pervasive. Redux is not always neccesary.

Comment: If you don't want to use Redux, then I suggest passing the Media Player object to the PlayButton and in the PlayButton add event listeners such play/pause to update the state.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your function is in the parent component, you can pass it down as a function in props.

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {
  parentAlert = () => {
    alert('function from parent')
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child parentAlert={this.parentAlert}/>
      </div>
      )
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.props.parentAlert}>
        click me
      </button>
    )
  }
}

let id = document.getElementById('react')
ReactDOM.render(<Parent/>, id)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id='react'/>
```

Comment: This will not work. I need to be able to fire an event when the song has finished playing that will toggle the button state. I already have the `onClick` set up and working fine.

Comment: @DeveloperJames If this is not addressing your issue, please revise your subject title and make your wording more clear in the question itself.

Comment: It's in the question: `I need to call toggle so that when the track has reached the end the play button will toggle from playing, to stopped. Is this possible at all?`

Comment: @DeveloperJames so the `Lottie` component is firing a DOM event when the track reaches the end? You can add an event listener in the `componentDidMount` of your component - you can use `ReactDOM.findDOMNode()` to get a reference to the DOM node object.

Comment: @MattHolland Yes, except the other way around. I want the parent component (in this case the one that renders `<PlayButton ... />`) to fire an event when the track has finished playing. The result is to change the state of the play button when the song has finished playing, The same as Youtube when it finishes playing the pause button changes state to reload for example. The parent is the media player and controls audio, waveform, track data and play button. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

let say you have Parent Component

```
import React from 'react';

import Child from './Child';

class CompA extends React.Component {

  toggle = () => {
    alert("Toggle from main class called inside children component");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Child toggle={this.toggle} />
    )
  }
}

export default CompA;
```

and you wan't to call toggle from Child component like this

```
import React from 'react';

class Child extends React.Component {

   render() {
      setTimeout(() => { this.props.toggle() }, 3000);
      return (
          <div>
            Child
          </div>
      )
   }
}

export default Child;
```

Then you just pass reference to that function you wan't to call from child and invoke it in child component. You can invoke it whenever you need. There i've put it in setTimeout to call it after 3sec, and you can make your function that plays and when it ends to call it then.

Answer (score 0):

```js
class AAA extend React.Component {
    
    static call_this() {
      return 'Hello World';
    }
    
   // ...
}

class BBB extend React.Component {
    //...
    
   render() {
   
    AAA.call_this(); // return  'Hello World'
   
   }
  
}
```

but remember you can't access this keyword inside static method.